# How to use one Doxygen config in different OS

Tags: doxygen

I have Doxygen configuration file that generates the HTML file. In my project, some use Windows and Mac. When I ran in my Mac OS X I got the path slash problem, I changed `\` to `/` this solves the problem.

EDIT: I don't want the users to modify the Doxygen config file.

```
Windwos
    -INPUT                  = SDK\nRF5_SDK_15.2.0_9412b96\examples\
OS X compatible
    +INPUT                  = SDK/nRF5_SDK_15.2.0_9412b96/examples/
```

I don't want to have the separate Doxygen configuration file for Windows and Mac, I want to know is it possible to have one file that can work?

Is there any way I can set some environment parameter in Doxygen configuration that can solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can also use the forward slash(`/`) in the doxygen configuration file for the `INPUT` tag and most other tags requiring a path as well.

So by placing in the doxygen configuration file the:

`INPUT                  = SDK/nRF5_SDK_15.2.0_9412b96/examples/`

this should work on Windows and Mac OS X.

In case the path on Windows and the Mac is different you can use and environment variable (eg. MY_PATH), set it in the encompassing script and in the doxygen configuration file you can use:

`INPUT = $(MY_PATH)`

See also http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html (end of second paragraph).

Comment: I want one doxygen file that works in Windows and Mac, I don't want the user to edit the doxygen config file. Is there any way to do that?